# Getting an error "Ambiguous discriminator 'revamp@904" from MongoDB in F# (using C# lib)

Tags: c#, mongodb, f#

I'm trying to use MongoDB to cache some data for me, but I can't seem to get the code to return a specific collection.  I can get other collections without an issue, but for this one cannot get it to work and I have no idea why.  The only error that I get is:

> Ambiguous discriminator `'revamp@904'`

I have searched long and hard for any indication as to what this means.  Here's the code I'm using:

```ml
let GetCacheDataObject ctxName cacheName collection = 
    let ctx = new DataContext(ctxName)
    let q = Query.EQ("CacheName", BsonValue.Create(cacheName.ToString()))
    let entity =
        match ctx.Db.CollectionExists(collection) with
        | false -> null
        | _ -> ctx.Db.GetCollection(typeof<DataObject>, collection).FindOneAs<DataObject>(q)
    entity
```

Once it his the 'FindAsOne', this error gets thrown.

The DataObject is a very basic custom object to hold data.  Here's the definition:

```
public class DataObject:IHaveIdentifier
{
    public BsonObjectId _id { get; set; }
    //public long Id { get; set; }
    public string[] Columns { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<object[]> Rows { get; set; }
    public string CacheName { get; set; }
    public int GetColumnIndex(string column)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.Columns.Length; i++)
            if (this.Columns[i] == column)
                return i;

        return -1;
    }
}
```

And the IHaveIdentifier interface is pretty basic:

```
public interface IHaveIdentifier
{
    BsonObjectId _id { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the code that was used to save the data in the first place:

```
member x.Save<'T when 'T :> IHaveIdentifier>(entity:'T, collection:string) =
        if (entity._id = null ) then x.Insert<'T>(entity, collection)
        else
            x.Delete(entity, collection)
            x.Insert<'T>(entity, collection)
        x.VerifyNoErrors()

let CacheDataObject<'T when 'T :> IHaveIdentifier>(entity:'T, ctxName, collection) =
    let ctx = new DataContext(ctxName)
    ctx.Save(entity, collection)
```

This code was working the other day then something changed and I cannot seem to figure out what is going on.

UPDATE: Added initial saving code above

Comment: I know that `revamp` is an identifier used in FSharp.Core in seq.fs, in case that helps.  (I am guessing maybe this code is looking inside argument names of a lambda or something maybe?)

Comment: Brian, I kind of thought that but I haven't been able to see how.  The only parameters are all strings that are passed in.  Do you have any ideas of how I might trace that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brian and Robert,
Your input helped me figure out exactly what was going on.  I was able to determine that the IEnumberable Rows property was exactly the issue.  I was setting the Rows to a seq.  In F# Seq are lazily evaluated, which in this case meant that Rows was being set to the output value (kind of like a ref) of the function, not the actual result.  Once I converted the Rows using Seq.ToArray, then everything worked as expected.

Thanks you both so much for pointing me down the right path.

Answer (score 1):

Can you run the equivalent query in the mongo shell and see what the existing document looks like.

My suspicion is that it that has a "_t" value that is causing problems. If so, the issue isn't with the FindOne but rather with how the document was saved in the first place, so we might have to go further back and look at that.

Comment: It's also probably related to the IEnumerable<object[]> Rows property. Whenever something is declared as type object the serialized value is going to have a "_t" discriminator to tell the deserializer what actual type to instantiate when reading the data back. Perhaps some of your values are F# specific data types that the C# driver is not successfully handling (we haven't done any testing with F#).

Comment: Robert, I have added code that is used in the initial save. I checked in the console, and it seems to save it correctly (there are too many rows so I can't see all of them in the console). The rows are made up of several int values, 2 decimal objects, and a string which is sometimes null.  I did notice the decimal objects have quotes around them.  Let me know what else I can do or how I can check for a "_t" value.

Comment: You'll have to find the actual document that is failing to be read and look at that one in the mongo shell (maybe the first few documents you see if you just do a find are OK). Don't know if the document has confidential information, but if I could look at it that would help. Also, can you provide a stack trace?

Comment: BTW, I'm not familiar with F# so I'm not making much sense of that part... sorry.